# Create objects of the same class with different variables

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to know if it is possible to create objects of the same class with different variables each time in Java.

**Example:**
This method returns data from a URL with a JSON file and I would like to use it to create a post object.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public Post getData(String ... url) throws StreamReadException, DatabindException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(new URL(url[0]), Post.class);
}
```

But the .JSON may be:

```
{ "name": "Bob" }
```

But also:

```
{ "color": "Red", "width": "200", "height": "150" }
```

Or anything else.

Comment: Every instance of the same class always has the same fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Post` is a subclass of Map or JsonNode, then yes, it can hold any key-value pairs.

If `Post` looks like this, then no, it's strictly defined as only having one field.

```
public class Post {
  String name;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand.
```Post``` should extend ```ObjectMapper```?

Comment: That's not what I said. If you want to parse any JSON response, use a map or generic type like JsonNode/JsonTree from Jackson, not a specific class with hard coded fields